# Hibernate não Cria Tabelas de Acordo com Esquema

Tags: java, hibernate

Percebi é que o Hibernate parece não criar as tabelas da forma como deveria ser apresentada no banco de dados. Estou utilizando o MySql e percebi o seguinte:
Exemplo da estrutura: Tabela Curso e outra Professor, onde a tabela cursos tem um Foreing Key com o código do professor.

Se criar as tabelas direto pelo administrador do banco de dados,existe uma guia FOREING KEY que mostra as chaves estrangeiras criadas. E para teste final se eu faço a inclusão de um curso e utilizo um professor que não existe o administrador do banco de dados recusa.

Utilizando o Hibernate isso já não acontece. Nem a guia de chaves estrangeiras apresenta a chave estrangeira, o que faz com que seja possível fazer a inclusão de um curso e utilizar o código de um professor não existente.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CURSO")
public class Curso implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cur_codigo")
    private Long codigo;
    @Column(name = "cur_nome")
    private String nome;
    @Column(name = "cur_diashorario")
    private String diashorario;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cur_profcodigo", referencedColumnName = "prof_codigo", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "CUR_PRO_FK"))
    private Professor professor;
```

Será que está faltando algo conceitual que não esteja entendendo ?

Comment: Fiz teste na minha máquina usando postgres (Não tenho acesso ao mysql no trabalho), ele criou normalmente a foreign key com os nomes corretos. Eu deduzi que na classe `Professor` o `id` está mapeado desta forma: `@Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "prof_codigo")
 private Long codigo;` . Se puder postar mais detalhes da classe Professor.

Comment: @ Entity
@ Table(name = "PROFESSOR")
public class Professor implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @ Id // indica a chave primária
 @ GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // gera codigo autimático
 @ Column(name = "prof_codigo")
 private Long codigo;

 @ Column(name = "prof_nome", length = 50, nullable = false)
 private String nome;

Answer (score 1):

Na classe de Professor, crie uma lista de Curso, e use a anotação

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="professor")
private List<Curso> lsCurso;
```